# How to determine when exponential growth starts?

Tags: python

I have a simple diode curve and I want to determine in python the moment when my curve starts exponential growth. How do I even start about this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can easily determine when it becomes *non-linear*. Just compare 3 **I** values, say `I[V1], I[V2], I[V3]` (V1, V2, V3 should be consecutive voltage points) If `I[V2]/I[V1] == I[V3]/I[V2]` then you're still in the linear region.

Comment: In a real physical experiment of course it won't be _perfectly_ linear, so the check should be then that it is in some range (+/-) of the previous ratio.